# How can we test useState hooks inside a void function with jest and enzyme?

Tags: reactjs, unit-testing, jestjs, onclick, enzyme

I'm new to unit-testing and writing test cases using jest and enzyme in React. Can someone please help me to write the test case for this example?

```
const [open, setOpen] = useState(false);
const handleClose = () => {
    setOpen(!open);
}

//this handleClose is an onClick event
```

Comment: Simulate the click, assert on the user-visible result of the state change.

Comment: Sorry, I'm not able to get you. If you don't mind, could you please elaborate on it in an answer?

Comment: We can't see enough of your component to tell you exactly how to test it. Also SO is generally not a code-writing service - I'd recommend searching for relevant tutorials and going through those to understand how to use Jest and Enzyme generally.

Answer (score 1):

It must be done this way, validating where the open state will be used:

```
import { mount } from 'enzyme';
import React, { useState } from 'react'

const App = () => {
  const [open, setOpen] = useState(false);

  const handleClose = () => {
    setOpen(!open);
  };

  return (
    <>
      <button id="btn-click" onClick={handleClose}>
        Click here
      </button>
      <span id="is-open">{open ? "is open" : "is closed"}</span>
    </>
  );
};

it('when the button is clicked someone must be opened', () => {
  const wrapper = mount(<App />)
  wrapper.find('#btn-click').simulate('click')
  expect(wrapper.find('is-open').children()).toContain('is open')
})
```